# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method num_Clicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick, android-xml, navigation-drawer

I'm new to Android development. I just created navigation drawer with fragment of my own (simple calculator app). In that fragment I have added a click method for the buttons. But that is not working.
Note: I have defined the onclick method in xml view

calculator fragment:

```
public class SimpleCalcActivity extends Fragment {

    private TextView mDisplay;

    private boolean mDisplayIsEmpty = true;
    private boolean mFirstNumberReceived;
    private boolean mNumberEntered;
    private boolean mPointEntered;
    private double sNum1;
    private double sNum2;
    private static OperationsAndFunctions.OperEnum sOperation;
    private static OperationsAndFunctions.FuncEnum sFunction;
    private Animation anim;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable  ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_simplecalc,null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mDisplay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.resultview);
        mDisplay.setText("0");
    }

    public void num_Clicked(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) view;
        int number = 0;

        switch (button.getId()) {

            case R.id.n_one:
                number = 1;
                anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), 
R.anim.btn_anim);
                button.startAnimation(anim);
                break;
            case R.id.n_two:
                number = 2;
                anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), 
R.anim.btn_anim);
                button.startAnimation(anim);
                break;
           ...
    }
...
}
```

calculator view:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/o_root"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="@string/root"
    android:onClick="func_Clicked"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
<Button
    android:tag="nums"
    android:id="@+id/n_seven"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="@string/_7"
    android:onClick="num_Clicked"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

Navigation drawer:

`...
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_simple_calc) {

            fragment = new SimpleCalcActivity();

        }
    }

        if (fragment != null){
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.screen_area, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) 
findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    ...`

I have tried setOnClickListener Method, it does not worked for me
I'm looking for your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly you mean by not working, giving an error or not as per expectation

Comment: Provide your Error code also.

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment code is wrong. Try this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_dialog, container, false);

    cancelAction = view.findViewById(R.id.cancelActionId);

    cancelAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do anything.
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Your aren't Return the `view`.

Try to write code with this structure, your problem will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `num_Clicked()` method **`in Your Activity not Fragment`**.

Move the method to the activity in which you are using that fragment